# Using commit/rollback transactions in stored procedure is good OR bad approach

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, commit, rollback

I read many articles on google but didn't get an idea to use transaction in stored procedures while insertion/updation/deletion.

Anybody explain me is this good or bad.

Does it really effect stored procedure performance.

Thanks

Comment: A very broad question - in general transactions are good since they enforce atomicity of operations, but yes they can cause adverse performance depending on the nature of the queries enrolling in the transaction and what locks are taken on the data. Is there any specific issue you are having or is this just a general question?

Comment: Actually I have three tables TableA,TableB and TableC.First i insert record in TableA and get new identity and with this identity(which is foreign key in TableB) I insert record in TableB , get identity(which is foreign key in TableBC) from TableB and insert record in TableC with this identity.
I used transaction in SP and sometimes I feels it takes too much time to execute.
That's why i asked this question.

Comment: Depends on a lot of factors - how much time is too long? How much time would you expect it to take? What contention have you got on the table (i.e. how many other processes are waiting on or operating on the table during your transaction?)

Comment: I really thankful to all of you sharing your knowledge and giving me hints to make code better.
I think stackOverlow is the best platform now a days for any developer to clear doubt and adopt best programming approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First i insert record in TableA and get new identity and with this identity(which is foreign key in TableB) I insert record in TableB , get identity(which is foreign key in TableBC) from TableB and insert record in TableC with this identity.

The **only** solution is to use transactions. If you omit transaction in update that span multiple tables you are **guaranteed** to achieve inconsistent state.

> I used transaction in SP and sometimes I feels it takes too much time to execute

Correctness is not optional. If you have blocking issues, ask a separate question about how to investigate and troubleshoot blocking and performance problems.